# Proof help. Core-compactness, Hausdorff, Locally Compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness

While reading about topologies on continuous function spaces, I've seen remarks that core-compact and locally compact are equivalent for Hausdorff spaces.

Now I can clearly see that locally compact always implies core-compact, so the Hausdorff condition comes into the proof of the converse.

Let $K$ be a core-compact Hausdorff space. Let $x\in U\subseteq K$ with $U$ open. I need to show that $U$ contains a compact neighborhood of $x$. Since $K$ is core-compact there is an open neighborhood $V$ such that $x\in V\subseteq U$ with $V\ll U$.

I don't know where to go from here.

*EDIT*

Here are the two papers which make make me believe this is a theorem:

[Core Compactness and Diagonality in Spaces of Open Sets](http://agt.webs.upv.es/Volumes/V12N2/AGTV12N2143.pdf)

[Topologies on Spaces of Continuous Functions](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/228867420_Topologies_on_spaces_of_continuous_functions/file/5046351a6cf6d7ff79.pdf)

I have found another source which claims something better: every sober core-compact space
is locally compact (although I can't see the proof of the theorem; I might buy it).

[Non-Hausdorff Topology](http://books.google.com/books?id=QwjAV_t90IcC&pg=PA142&lpg=PA142&dq=core%20compact%20topology&source=bl&ots=O6ouj3b2De&sig=3azYgBR5e37rnFWwL6kUNgiEHwQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Ak_pUt3zEqGMyQGmqIDADw&ved=0CGgQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=core%20compact%20topology&f=false)

This hints that the property of Hausdorff spaces that we want to exploit is the fact that the intersection of all closed neighborhoods of a point is precisely that point.

**EDIT**

I am now asking for help in completing the proof. This has been bothering me for too long.

Comment: What does core-compact mean?

Comment: Every neighborhood $U$ of every point $x$ contains a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that every open cover of $U$ contains a finite subcover of $V$.

Comment: Hmm... Wouldn't the closure of this $V$ be compact? Since if $(W_i)_I$ is an open cover of $\bar V$, then $(W_i)_I\cup\{U-\bar V\}$ is an open cover of $U$. Then it contains a finite subcover of $V$, but $U-\bar V$ is not part of this subcover, so the subvocer must also cover $\bar V$.

Comment: But I wouldn't know that $\overline{V}\subseteq U$.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I forgot that $\bar V$ need not be a subset of $U$. But maybe you can take the relative closure. The relative closure of $V$ in $U$ is equal to $\bar V\cap U$.

Comment: If I tried to create an open cover of $U$ the same way, I wouldn't know $\overline{V}^c\cup U^c$ is open.

Comment: Where do you need $\bar V^c\cup U^c$ ?

Comment: If I were trying to prove that $\overline{V}\cap U$ is compact I'd let $\{V_\alpha\}$ be an open cover of it. Then I'd have to account for $\overline{V}^c\cup U^c$ as this set isn't necessarily empty and not necessarily covered by our open cover.

Comment: I can prove that $K$ is $T_{2.5}$ if that helps any, since compact sets are closed.

Comment: Given a cover $(W_i)_I$ of $\bar V\cap U$ consisting of open subsets of $U$, we can enlarge it by $U-\bar V$. This is then an open cover of $U$, so it contains a finite subcover of $V$. By my comment above, this finite subcover also covers $\bar V\cap U$.

Comment: In the comment above, I agree that the set $U-\overline{V}$ is not part of the subcover which covers $V$, but how do you conclude then that $\overline{V}$ is still contained in that same subcover though?

Comment: For example $V=(x+\epsilon,y-\epsilon)\ll(x,y)=U$. $\overline{V}=[x+\epsilon,y-\epsilon]$ and if we take the open cover $V_n=(x+\epsilon-1/n,x-\epsilon+1/n)$ and attach $U-\overline{V}=[x+1/n)\cup(y-1/n]$ we do get an open cover of $U$. But deleting $U-\overline{V}$ gives us our original cover which does not cover $\overline{V}$.

Comment: Okay, thanks for pointing that out, I was thinking of another proof (the one that closed subsets of compact spaces are compact) and it somehow sneaked into this.

Comment: In the example, I meant $U-\overline{V}=(x, x+\epsilon)\cup(y-\epsilon,y)$.

Comment: So we can only say that every open cover of $\bar V\cap U$ contains a finite subcover of $V$.

Comment: Yes. Perhaps we can prove regularity? In the closed neighborhood basis form? That would finish it.

Comment: If we start with everything in the original post, regularity would imply there is a closed set $x\in C\subseteq V$ with nonempty interior. Take an open cover of $C$ and add $C^c$. That's an open cover of $U$ containing a finite subcover of $V$. And we can remove $C^c$.

Comment: That works. But how do show regularity? Nonetheless, we can be sure that the space will be regular, if the result is true.

Comment: There is a result which says that in a Hausdorff space, a point can be separated by neighborhoods from a disjoint compact subset. However, that does not cover all disjoint closed subsets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably not the quickest but here is a suggestion for core-compact $\Rightarrow$ local regularity.

Let $z \in X$.  Let $z \in V \subset U$ as in the definition of core compact.  Let $x \in V$ and $E \subset V$ a closed subset not containing $x$.  For each $y \in F=\overline{E}^U$ choose an open neighborhood $U_y$ with $x \notin \overline{U_y}$ which we may do because $X$ is Hausdorff. The cover $\{U_{y}\}_{y \in F} \cup \{ F^c =U \setminus F \}$ is an open cover of $U$ and so has a finite subcover $U_{y_1},...,U_{y_n}, F^c$ which covers $V$.

Set $U' = U_{y_1} \cup U_{y_2} \cup ... \cup U_{y_n}$. The open set $U'$ covers $E$.

$x \notin \overline{U_{y_1}},...,\overline{U_{y_n}}$ by construction of the open sets $U_y$ so $x \notin \overline{U'}$.  That is to say, $V$ is regular.

**Rest of proof from the comment section added for completeness:**
First use local regularity to reduce to the case when $U$ is regular.
Let $z \in X$ and $z \in V \subset U$ as in the definition of core compact.  $U$ is regular by assumption so there exists a closed neighborhood $C \subset V$ containing $z$.  Any open cover of $C$ extends to an open cover of $U$ by adding in $U \setminus C$.  Any such open cover has a finite subcover covering $V$ which covers $C$.  Removing the set $U \setminus C$ from this finite subcover yields a finite subcover of $C$.

Comment: Why couldn't $x\in\overline{U''}$? In addition to that, I'm confused why you introduced sequences. We do not know that our space is even sequential.

Comment: Actually, you only need local regularity so it simplifies.

Comment: One final thing. I follow how you got that points and closed sets (closed in $X$) in $V$ can be separated by open neighborhoods, but how does that get you a closed set (closed in $X$) $C\subseteq V$ with $z\in C$? I know that regularity can be formulated in two different ways (as neighborhoods or closed sets), but does that extend to local regularity?

Comment: "Every neighborhood U of z contains a V ...." is the definition of core-compact.  Therefore we may assume that U is regular and C is closed in U which is all that we need.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done easily with *ultrafilters*. Similarly to the ultrafilter characterisation of compactness, $V\ll U$ is equivalent to saying that each ultrafilter containing $V$ has a limit in $U$.

For the proof, let $x\in X$. By core-compactness, we can choose open neighborhoods $U$ and $V$ of $x$ such that $V\ll U$ and $U\ll X$. All ultrafilters containing $V$ have no limit outside of $U$, since they already have a limit in $U$, and they can only have one limit thanks to Hausdorffness. But this means that $\overline{V}\subseteq U$. Hence every ultrafilter containing $\overline{V}$ contains $U$, and since $U\ll X$, these ultrafilters converge. As $\overline{V}$ is closed, they converge to something in $\overline{V}$. So $\overline{V}$ is compact. So $x$ has a compact neighborhood.

Answer (score 1):

This would be better suited as a comment but I cannot yet do that.

You would probably find a proof online quite easily if you searched for "exponentiability" but for a more specific proof go for "A Compendium of Continous Lattices" ( You can find this online ) by Gierz, Hofmann, Keimel, Lawson, Mislove, Scott. I believe there is shown straightforwardly something like given Hausdorff space and $U, V$ open then $U \ll V$ implies existence of compact $W$ so that $U \subseteq W \subseteq V$.